# .NET SQL insert slow compared to JDBC? (JDBC 4x faster)

Tags: java, .net, sql, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I done some test between .NET Native SQL Client in C# and compared to the JDBC driver in java and i was blown away by the result, and thinking i must have done something wrong in the .net code. 
Result for 1 million inserts in a table with a integer and a text field i empty it before each  try, running the programs build for release and by them self.

- .NET 1 million rows 1 transaction with prepared statements took 159
  seconds.
- java with JDBC driver from microsoft 1 million rows 1    transaction
  with prepared statments took 39 seconds.

**JDBC is 4 times faster Why?**

Im kinda stunned that the .NET is so much slower and really hope that i made a big mistake with my .net code. So anyone have any idea whats wrong or why .NET is so much slower then jdbc?

.NET code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=testameep;User Id=sa;Password=********;");
        con.Open();
        String tempString = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<400;i++)
        {
            tempString += "insert into test1 values (@A" + i.ToString() + ",@B" + i.ToString() + " );";
        }

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(tempString,con);
        for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
        {
            com.Parameters.Add("@A" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.Int);
            com.Parameters.Add("@B" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.NVarChar,4000);
        }
        com.Transaction = con.BeginTransaction();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        com.Prepare();
        for(int i=0;i<2500;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<800;j+=2)
            {
                com.Parameters[j].Value = i;
                com.Parameters[j + 1].Value = "test";
            }
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        com.Transaction.Commit();
        label1.Text = "Query took:" + (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds + " ms";
```

java code:

```
Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" );
      String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=testameep;user=sa;password=*******";
      Connection dbCon = DriverManager.getConnection( dbURL, "sa" , "*******" );
      dbCon.setAutoCommit( false );

      String tempString = "";
      for(int i = 0;i<400;i++)
      {
          tempString += "insert into test1 values (?,?);";
      }
      System.out.println("Query start");
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      PreparedStatement ps = dbCon.prepareStatement(tempString);
      for(int i=0;i<2500;i++)
      {
          for (int j=1;j<800;j+=2)
          {
              ps.setInt(j, i);
              ps.setString( j+1, "test");
          }
              ps.executeUpdate();
      //    ps.addBatch();
      }
          //This gave the same speed/result as using ps.executeUpdate();
      //ps.executeBatch();
      ps.close();
      dbCon.commit();
      double total = (double)(System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000.0;
      System.out.printf("Query stop: %f seconds\n", total);
```

Update:
SQL Profiler results
.NET:

```
--Creating the prepared statement .NET
 declare @p1 int
 set @p1=1
 exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@A0 int,@B0 nvarchar(4000),@A1 int,@B1 nvarchar(4000),@A2    int,@B2 nvarchar(4000),@A3 int,@B3 nvarchar(4000),@A4 int,@B4 nvarchar(4000),@A5 int,...(continues)
select @p1

--Inserting rows .NET
exec sp_execute   1,@A0=4,@B0='test',@A1=4,@B1='test',@A2=4,@B2='test',@A3=4,@B3='test',@A4=4,@B4='test',@A5=4,@B5='test',@A6=4,@B6='test',@A7=4,@B7='test',@A8=4,@B8='test',@A9=4,...(continues)
...
2500 rows
```

SQL Profiler results
JDBC:

```
--Creating the prepared statment JDBC
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,N'@P0 int,@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 int,@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4    int,@P5 nvarchar(4000),@P6 int,@P7 nvarchar(4000),@P8 int,@P9 nvarchar(4000),@P10 int,...  (continues)
select @p1

--Inserting rows JDBC
exec sp_execute   1,5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5,N'test',5...(continues)
...
2500 rows
```

Comment: Both are not using bulk insert, you know. Like in SqlBulkCopy class in .NET.

Comment: Okey, maybe bulk insert is the wrong thing to call it. But both does the same kind of insertes. gonna remove the bulk from the title. I guess you didnt read the java code.

Comment: Don't know why it was downvoted. I tested the code and got the same results. Can't really say why it should be faster with JDBC. Any Profiler/Tracer output to check?

Comment: Updated with the profiler results and noticed that the .NET code inserted varchar(250) and the JDBC a nvarchar(4000) so i changed the .NET code but it still have the same slow performance compared to JDBC @stefan

Comment: What if you save the traced result and run them thro the performance tuner? To see if it has anything to do with the generated SQL code (variables are handled differently) rather than .NET overhead?

Comment: The performance tuner didnt say anything 0% on both .NET and JDBC. @stefan

Answer (score 0):

```
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();  
    }  
    com.Transaction.Commit();
```

vs

```
     ps.addBatch(); 
  } 
  ps.executeBatch(); 
  ps.close();   
  dbCon.commit();
```

Method of execution looks diffent to me

Comment: I reckon this is spot on. You are executing on every iteration of the loop in .NET.

Comment: I first had ps.executeUpdate(); instead of the ps.addBatch() and ps.executeBatch(); but it was the same performance on both. I updated and commented in the code aswell now

Comment: Rather than doing that, I'd move ExecuteNonQuery out of the loop and leave the java code as is. If you are going to the trouble of creating a huge statement to test, then make sure it is executed in its entirety once. Also try using StopWatch in .NET too to determine length of execution.

Comment: @mr-b Also tried to put a sleep(5000) in the java application in the loop where executeUpdate runs and watch the SQL Profiler. The result was it took 5 seconds between each line in the SQL Profiler so it sends it as it executes exactly as the .NET application does.

Comment: @mr-moose i changed to a console app and using stopwatch instead same result. And i cant move the com.ExecuteNonQuery() outside the loop then it will only insert 400 rows....